# Reading revision string in post-deploy hook

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, revision

I though this would be easy but I cannot manage to find a way to get the revision string from a post deploy hook on EBS. The use case is straightforward: I want to warn rollbar of a deploy.

Here is the current script :

```
# Rollbar deploy notifier
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/90_notify_rollbar.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      . /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/envvars

      LOCAL_USERNAME=`whoami`
      REVISION=`date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S`

      curl https://api.rollbar.com/api/1/deploy/ \
        -F access_token=$ROLLBAR_KEY \
        -F environment=$RAILS_ENV \
        -F revision=$REVISION \
        -F local_username=$LOCAL_USERNAME
```

So far I'm using the current date as revision number, but that isn't really helpful. I tried using `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config` but I couldn't find anything relevant in the `environment` and `container` section, and couldn't read anything from `meta`. Plus, I found no doc about those, so...

Ideally, I would also like the username of the deployer, not the one on the local machine, but that would be the cherry on the cake.

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0):

You can update your elastic beanstalk instance profile role (aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role) to allow it to call Elastic Beanstalk APIs. In the post deploy hook you can call DescribeEnvironments with the current environment name using the aws cli or any of the AWS SDKs.
Let me know if you have any more questions about this or if this does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for an easy alternative for API. For now I use bash

```
eb deploy && curl https://api.rollbar.com/api/1/deploy/ -F access_token=xxx -F environment=production -F revision=`git rev-parse --verify HEAD` -F rollbar_username=xxx
```

Replace `xxx` with your token and username